# nextjs 13.4 app router , APIs endpoint POST , can't json() "parse" the request to access the body

Tags: post, next.js, request, app-router

```html
export async function POST(req:Request) {
  
  try {
    const body = await req.json()
    console.log(body);
    return new Response("ok")
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

}
```

when using postman to send a payload , the server console spits an 500 internal server error and
this code will spit this :

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected number in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parseJSONFromBytes (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6498:19)
    at successSteps (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:6472:27)
    at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:1145:60
    at node:internal/process/task_queues:140:7
    at AsyncResource.runInAsyncScope (node:async_hooks:204:9)
    at AsyncResource.runMicrotask (node:internal/process/task_queues:137:8)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

EDIT : the endpoint i'm trying to reach is in app/api/testPost/route.tsx
Postman ScreenShot  : screenShot[image: using form-data tab]

[image: folder hierarchy]

Comment: Can you show the data you are sending from postman, and also a screenshot? This more likely due to a non correctly formatted data.

Comment: In postman, chose raw and then JSON if want to parse the body as JSON.

Comment: omg i'm such noob , thanks

Comment: We all have been and will be somehow :)

Answer (score 0):

Comment out   output: 'export' in next.config.js file and try again.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).